# ng-grid and custom directives with images

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, ng-grid

We are having pretty major issues with ng-grid and directives.

Basically we have an ng-grid, and we have a directive that supplies an image.

**What we have done:-**

1. created a simple directive that displays an image
   issue :- on scrolling the image tended to jump up and down onto different rows
2. After much googling, discovered that we should use a $watch statement, 
   so now our directive looks like :-

.

```
MyLists.directive('status', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        template: '<div ng-switch="alert">' +
                    '<div ng-switch-when=""></div>' +
                    '<div ng-switch-default><img src="{{alert}}.ictrl" /></div>' +
                  '</div>',    
        scope: { alertData: '=alertData' },        
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {            
            function updateICAlert(stralert) {
                scope.alert = "";
                if ((stralert !== null) && (stralert !== undefined) && (stralert !== '')) {
                    scope.alert = stralert;
                }
                return scope.alert;
            } //function    
            scope.$watch('alertData', function (oldValue, newValue) {                
                if (newValue) {
                    updateICAlert(scope.alertData);
                }
            });           
        }           
    }
});
```

This now at least stops the image from jumping rows, however,  the new issue :-

the grid is now suddenly running really slow, and clicking on the column header (for ordering) is also duplicating data..

Are we missing something with this?

Comment: Why use a directive to display an image? Wouldn't it be a lot easier to use a cell template?

Comment: @mainguy We are using the directive as we have logic in a couple of them to display certain images based on scope values

Comment: Can you show me more of your implementation? How do you define the grid? What is an .ictrl?? How much data is in your grid and what does it look like? Because here your directive is working fine. No lag, no duplicates.

Comment: Plz check what happens if you leave out the if(newValue) in the watcher.